# Half Arrow in UMLet

Tags: uml, tool-uml, umlet

I am trying to draw collaboration diagrams that have asynchronous connections using UMLet. I need to draw a half arrow, but I can't see if the tool has this functionality. Does anyone know how to do this?

By a half arrow, I mean something like this:

```
  /_____    or  _____\
```

in Unicode, 21C0 is an example (called a 'harpoon').

Thank you!